# PHPStan: Parameter #1 $length of function random_bytes expects int<1, max>, int given

Tags: php, phpstan

I'm getting a PHPStan error that I don't understand how to fix:

> Parameter #1 $length of function random_bytes expects int<1, max>, int
> given.

The function is very simple:

```
  private function generateEncryptionKey(int $bytes = 16): string {
    return bin2hex(random_bytes($bytes));
  }
```

I don't know why the error is `expects int<1, max>` because I typehint `$bytes` to `int` and [random_bytes takes an int as the argument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php).

So what is the meaning of the error PHPStan is identifying here, and how can I fix it?

The PHPStan online demo also [reports this as an error](https://phpstan.org/r/7a45b7b3-d628-4289-a961-a08b0715df16).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expects to have a minimum of length 1, but you could call it with a length of 0 which would fail.

#### Fix

You can fix this by calling with a `max(1, $bytes)` which will have at least 1 byte, even if a 0 is passed.

[Demo](https://phpstan.org/r/8259c5a0-c285-4ab8-9764-37d8f5df3605)

#### Note

I changed to public static for testing purpose, but you can change back to private.

#### Code

```
class HelloWorld
{
      public static function generateEncryptionKey(int $bytes = 16): string {
          return bin2hex(random_bytes(max(1, $bytes)));
      }
}
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, negative integers are also possible parameters for `generateEncryptionKey()`.